# Centering left justified text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I need to define a new environment that contains a minipage centered on the current page and with text left-justified.

Something like:

```
\newenvironment{texto}{
   \begin{center} % so the minipage is centered
   \begin{minipage}[t][\textwidth]
   \begin{flushleft} % so the minipage's text is left justified
}{
   \end{flushleft}
   \end{minipage}
   \end{center}
}
```

I've been trying for hours without luck so far.

If it was possible to put the minipage inside a centered makebox inside the new environment it would be possible, but there's no makebox environment.

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final]{book}
\newenvironment{code-block}{
    \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \raggedright
}{
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

a completely random line, filled with random words, or perhaps not!

\begin{code-block}
pineapples with mustard
\end{code-block}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To allow for a variable-width `minipage` environment, you need the [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth). From the [package documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth):

> The package deﬁnes a `varwidth` environment (based on `minipage`)
>   which is an analogue of `minipage`, but whose resulting width is the
>   natural width of its contents.

The minimal example as presented in the package documentation gives a view on what means:

[image: An example of the varwidth environment from the package documentation]

So, alter [Stefan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25580/centering-left-justified-text/25581#25581) in the following way:

```
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
\newenvironment{texto}{%
  \begin{center} % so the minipage is centered
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\textwidth}
  \raggedright % so the minipage's text is left justified
}{%
  \end{varwidth}
  \end{center}
}
```

[image: varwidth vs minipage]

Comment: @joca: Nice to see that Werner's solution works for you! I've noticed, you accepted his answer, it would also be great if you vote it up as you saw it's useful, just by clicking the arrow on the left of his post - I did.

Comment: I tried, but I am not registered.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a suggestion:

```
\newenvironment{texto}[1][\textwidth]{
   \begin{center} % so the minipage is centered
   \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}
   \raggedright % so the minipage's text is left justified
}{
  \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
}
```

- I used the declaration `\raggedright` instead of the `flushleft` environment since the effect is limited by the outer minipage environment.
- I introduced an optional argument for the mandatory width of the minipage.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newenvironment{texto}[1][\textwidth]{
   \begin{center} % so the minipage is centered
   \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}
   \raggedright % so the minipage's text is left justified
}{
  \end{minipage}
   \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{texto}[6cm]
  \blindtext
\end{texto}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: @joca: you could be more specific. I'll add a minimal example showing that it does work.

Comment: See my edit, my minimal example shows it does not work.

Comment: @joca: Your minimal example *does* work. You are typesetting a `minipage` of width `\textwidth` (by default, since you don't specify any other length like in [Stefan's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25580/centering-left-justified-text/25581#25581)) and justify it `\raggedright`. Specifying a minipage of width `\textwidth` will produce something that looks similar to just removing the `minipage` altogether, resulting in exactly what you presented. That is, centering a `minipage` of width `\textwidth` does nothing visually. Do you want to have a modified width for the `minipage`?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry then. I want the minipage to scale to contain the text inside it (it will contain verbatim-like text), I don't know the dimension before hand. Sometimes it can be 6cm, 4cm, etc.